# Start VM in Azure, don’t have runas rights to use VM start runbook in azure automation

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, startup

I want to power on azure vm name “test server” that gets poweroff everyday after work. Is there another way to power it on? Is it possible to create a cron job on the test server to power on after it was shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know that does not need a service principal is [Azure DevTest Labs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devtest-lab/). You can configure [auto startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/lab-services/devtest-lab-auto-startup-vm) for lab machines. Since you can set up a VM within DevTest labs just like any other VM, it fits most of these cases quite well.

> Azure DevTest Labs allows you to configure virtual machines in your lab to be automatically started and shutdown based on a schedule.

No idea why this is not built in for normal VMs, that is how it is.